# Notation of $P^+$-families - bibliography searching

Tags: reference-request, notation, ultrafilters

have you ever met with notation of $P^+$-families in other papers than Iian B. Smythe "A local Ramsey theory for block sequences" and his phd? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: $P^+$-filters are quite common in the literature. Can you provide the definition of a $P^+$-family?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Up to my knowledge, a family $A$ is "standard" $P^+$ - family if each countable subset of $A$ has pseudointersection in $A^+$. But I'm looking for a non-standard understending of this notation. The reason is following: I've written a paper with the definition (in short): let us call {\it contur} first iteration of Fr\'{e}chet filter (by Frolik sum = tensor produkt =..) The family $A$ with fip {\it is not quasi finer than a contur} if for each countable family $B$, such that $A \cup B$ fas fip,  there is no contur $C$ such that $\langle A \cup B \rangle \supset C$.

Comment: I've send a manuscript to IJM and the referee write, that this definition is well known as a $P^+$-family. Since obviousely those definition describes different classes of families, thus I'm looking "non-standard" definition of the $P^+$-family. By the way, if you would like to look at the paper an old version is on Arxive https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03862v3.pdf  (with one incorectness and a different notation: for "is not quasi finer than a contur" is used "is not EQ-subbase of the contur"), a new wersion I'll add to Arxive soon. 
Best regards